# Tracking state change of an entity

Tags: java, jpa, entity, eclipselink

I have a need to track he state change of a java entity class that uses MySQL as its database. I know the EntityManager has a mechanism to track state change for the entities it is managing. What I want is to access the entity state change. I want my application to fire an even to inform another application regarding the the new state of the entity. From what I gathered so far, there is no API that I can use to check the particular life-cycle an entity is in. Or is there?
Does any one have information on how to approach this?

Comment: What language and framework/orm/library are you using?

Comment: Java, I am using eclipse-link JPA.

Comment: You should add those as tags to a question. I went ahead and added them for you this time ;-)

Comment: Thanks @prodigitalson;  I'll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA defines **listener interfaces**, that you can implement in order to be notified of **lifecycle events** for the entities.

Have a look at this article: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event

Answer (score 2):

EclipseLink provides a set of events at the session level (SessionEventListener).

I assume you only want to notify of committed changes, after they have been committed?  For this you can use the postCommitUnitOfWork event.  The event/uow contain a UnitOfWorkChangeSet that contains the list of changes that were made in the transaction.